# Python for loop not iterating as expected

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to write an annotator which loops through a list of names, tagging a separate document when these names appear. These names can consist of one or two words.

The buffer on the program works, so it recognises whether it needs to look at one or both lines of the file for tagging, and tags when the name which comes up matches the candidate exactly.

However, instead of looping through all the names in the list for each candidate, takes the name in the loop it has on that particular round and if the name does not match the candidate, writes the line and moves onto the next line (with the next name in the list). This obviously results in there being many names in the file which are not tagged when they should be.

Below is my code:

```
import json
from tagging import import_names


def split_line(line):
    """Split a line into four parts, word, pos, lemma and tag."""
    # TODO: Speak to Diana about the spaces in the vert file - do they mean
    # anything?
    line = line.strip().split()
    if len(line) == 1:
        word = line[0]
        pos, lemma, tag = None, None, None
    elif len(line) == 3:
        word, pos, lemma = line
        tag = ''
    elif len(line) == 4:
        word, pos, lemma, tag = line
    return [word, pos, lemma, tag]


class MWUTagger(object):
    """Contains a buffer of lines split into word, pos, lemma, tag items."""
    def __init__(self, f_in, f_out, n, gnrd_file, indicators=None):
        """Populate the buffer."""
        # read the input vert file
        self.f_in = open(f_in, 'r')
        # populate the buffer (first n lines of the vert file)
        self.buffer = []
        for i in range(n):
            self.buffer.append(split_line(self.f_in.readline()))
        # read in list of names or save
        self.names = import_names(gnrd_file)
        # create the output vert file
        self.f_out = f_out

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def write_line(self):
        """Write out the oldest line in the buffer, and add a new line to the buffer."""
        # write the oldest line from the buffer
        tagged_line = self.buffer.pop(0)
        tagged_line = [i for i in tagged_line if i]
        with open(self.f_out, 'a') as f:
            if tagged_line[0].startswith('<') and tagged_line[-1].endswith('>'):
                f.write(' '.join(tagged_line) + '\n')
            else:
                f.write('\t'.join(tagged_line) + '\n')

    def __next__(self):
        """write out the oldest line in the buffer and add a new line to the buffer"""
        #write the oldest line from the buffer
        self.write_line()
        # add a new line to the buffer (found an example here https://bufferoverflow.com/a/14797993/1706564)
        line = self.f_in.readline()
        if line:
            self.buffer.append(split_line(line))
        else:
            self.f_in.close()
            self.flush()
            raise StopIteration

    def flush(self):
        """Write all remaining lines from buffer file to the output file"""
        while self.buffer:
            self.write_line()

    def check_for_name(self, name):
        """Depending on length of name, check if the first n items in the buffer
        match name."""
        # check if tagged
        if self.buffer[0][-1] == 'SCI':
            return
        name = name.strip().split()
        name = [n + '-n' for n in name]
        n = len(name)
        # check if they match
        candidate = [line[2] for line in self.buffer[:n]]
        if name == candidate:
            # edit the tags in the first n items in the buffer if they do
            for i in range(n):
                self.buffer[i][-1] += "SCI%i" % (i + 1)
        # check if other names in the dictionary match 

def main():
    mwutagger = MWUTagger('zenodo_test_untag.vert', 'zenodomwutagged.vert', 2,'JSON_file_test.json')
    while True:
        try:
            for name in mwutagger.names:
                mwutagger.check_for_name(name)
                mwutagger.__next__()
        except StopIteration:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main ()
```

I am unsure if I need to add something into the check_for_name module to say if candidate =! name, go to next name til the end of the list until last list then just print, or if that is not being adequately handled in the main method.

Can anyone give me advice on this?

Comment: My advice is to write a [MCVE] of the problem,  this helps us answer but also is a valuable step in debugging.

Comment: The problem was where I was looping  through the names. Instead of this being in the main method, it needed to be within the check_for_name method.